# iOS - What Size Should I Use Under Simulated Metrics In Interface Building When Building UI With AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

Before, I always set size under simulated metrics to iphone 4, then compact width regular height, which is for all iphones in portrait. This is because I thought that when I do layout properly for the smallest screen size, then the outcome will definitely be good at other bigger screen sizes.

I thought of setting it to inferred, but the size of the simulated template seems difficult for me to design for iphone 4. Because iphone 4 is only 3.5 inches, the template is too long for that.

They say that we only need one set of layout with storyboard then we can already cover up all sizes and orientations for all iphones. But up until now I still don't know the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes absolutely no difference what simulated size you use in Interface Builder. This has no effect at all on what will happen when the app runs. The *real* size will be different for different devices. The whole point of autolayout is that is works for any size of device. Your job is to create layout that will look good on any device this app can run on.

Comment: You mean to say that even if I choose to create all my layouts on a 5.5-inch iphone, as long as I make sure that it looks good on that size, then it will definitely look good on other sizes? Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. I mean to say that you must design auto layout constraints to ensure that it looks good at any size, so the size you happen to use while drawing the interface is irrelevant. You might just as well design it on a 1000 by 1000 square. It is the constraints that matter.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!